# How to speak to specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working on a google implementation, now I want to change the font size when zoom level is 18 but if i execute my code below it speaks to all its markers:

```
  var id = locations[i][0].id;


  if (map.getZoom() === 18) {



        if( id >= 100 ){
            console.log(id);
            console.log($('[data-id="'+id+'"]'));

            //$('[data-id="'+id+'"]').css({'color' : 'red' ,'font-size' : '10px'});
            //$('[data-id="'+id+'"]').find('.number-id').css('font-size', '10px', '!important');

            $('#'+id).css('font-size', '10px', '!important');
        }
```

As you see I set `id` as an selector which finds the span where the `id/number` is shown but it won't change it style!

Here is my array of markers:

```
 var locations = [
    [{id: 1,  lat: 51.5239935252832,   lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 2,  lat: 51.523853342911906, lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 3,  lat: 51.5237298485607,   lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 4,  lat: 51.52355628836575,  lng:  5.138066234932012,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 5,  lat: 51.52340275379578,  lng:  5.138211074218816,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 6,  lat: 51.523199152806626, lng:  5.138382735595769,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 7,  lat: 51.5229955509073,   lng:  5.138511481628484,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 8,  lat: 51.52280529912936,  lng:  5.138543668136663,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 9,  lat: 51.523596340777075, lng:  5.138463201866216,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 700,lat: 51.523372714362736, lng:  5.1386992362595265,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}]
```

And this is the html of the marker:

```
var number = locations[i][0].id;
var marker_html = '<div class="rich-marker">'+'<span data-id="'+ number + '" class="number-id">' + number + '</span>' + '</div>';

//var marker_html = '<div id="'+ number + '"><div class="rich-marker"><span class="number-id">'+ number + '</span></div></div>';
```

Comment: maybe add an data-tag with the id of the marker (```<span data-id="1"></span>```)
 to your marker and set the color with ```$('[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('color', 'red');```

Comment: @Evolutio Why is this working and my way not/

Comment: I tested it and added an marker with the id of 701 it only changes the style of the last one

Comment: $(id) or $('#'+id) or $('.'+id) ???

Comment: Why should it be $('#'+id) or $('.'+id)???? The id  is an javascript variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working I'd do it like this:

Add an data-tag with the id of the marker to your marker-tag (`<span data-id="1"></span>`)

To set the css for the marker tih the id 1, you can use this:

`// example 
var id = 1;`

To style the marker, you can use this:

`$('[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('color', 'red');`

Your example dont work, because your id's are 1,2,3,4,5..
and you html should have this ids (#1,#2,#3,#4..)

and should look like this:

```
var marker_html = '<div id="1"><div class="rich-marker">'+'<span class="number-id">' + number + '</span>' + '</div></div>';
```

with this html markup you can use this piece of jQuery:

```
$('#'+id).find('.number-id').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer look at this fiddle to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/wezj0dbp/

Comment: I tried it with data-id and it seems to work with it changes it color to red for both, but the font-size is staying on 12 for one of the two examples

Comment: Even when I say change all `.number-id` to red it changes all to red but the font-size is only set for the last one!

Comment: Both ways it works only for the last object in array

Comment: Can you help me out on this?

Comment: Edit your marker html with both markers above in your question.

Comment: Do you understand my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112232/discussion-between-evolutio-and-beginnerprogrammer).